# Selecting only one feature from layer and making others to disappear in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, layers, select

I have a map with a series of points representing stores showing up. All these stores are from the same *.shp*-file and thus on the same layer in QGIS.

What i need to do is be able to select only one of these points and make the others *'disappear'* as long as that single other point is selected. I don't need the other points to disappear entirely (stating this cause I found a question on this forum suggesting a way to do this).

Also adding that the points are linked to another layer with isochrones (computed with orstools) that i need to show up with the selected point
does anyone know if there a way to do this in QGIS?